# How to initialize layouts in a packed way, reducing space between layouts?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlayout, qformlayout

I have several QHBoxLayout's that are all contained in a QVBoxLayout.

```
QHBoxLayout *hb1 = new QHBoxLayout;
// ...
QHBoxLayout *hb2 = new QHBoxLayout;
// ...

QWidget *hb1_layout = new QWidget;
hb1_layout->setLayout(hb1);

QWidget *hb2_layout = new QWidget;
hb2_layout->setLayout(hb2);

// ...

QVBoxLayout *ps = new QVBoxLayout;
ps->addWidget(hb1_layout);
ps->addWidget(hb2_layout);
ps->addWidget(hb3_layout);
ps->addWidget(hb4_layout);
```

What I'm trying to do is pack the widgets within each QHBoxLayout closer to the widgets in the QHBoxLayout next down. I.e., there's a lot of space between each row of widgets between the horizontal layouts.

When resizing the window, there needs to be a minimum size that the widgets won't go beyond. But when resizing larger, they evenly spread out.

If I resize the window, I can get it to look like what I want. But I don't know how to programmatically initialize the window to the right size in the first place. When I start my app, I have to minimize by resizing the window to get the widgets to appear nicely packed.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't use QGridLayout because the widgets are of different sizes and aren't evenly spaced, besides, they look too "gridy" when doing so. Will add detail to the question.

Comment: I don't see how this is particular. I just want widgets to appear closer together between the horizontal layouts. Your comments make me think this may be normal and maybe I need to reconsider my expectations.

Comment: Or maybe you can listen to me and provide a [mcve], many things have default values ​​so if you provide an example of your problem we could give you a better approach or a general solution, but as you do not we will not be able help him. Is it so hard to create a [mcve]?, I recommend reading [ask] and understand why we ask certain things.

Comment: I'll work on the example. There's a lot that I can't show for NDA reasons so I'll need to remove some stuff.

Comment: Well aware of what it is, and no one mentioned publishing the project. Calm down.

Comment: I'm calming down, I only said it because you mentioned about NDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> programmatically initialize the window to the right size in the first place.

use `adjustSize();` to set window size fit your widgets.

> What I'm trying to do is pack the widgets within each QHBoxLayout
>   closer to the widgets in the QHBoxLayout next down.

`QVBoxLayout` won't do it straightforward .. , instead use a `QFormLayout`, the rows do not *spread out* on their own, the rows just expand to their contents. you can adjust the *spacing* between rows to a suitable `int` value, `QFormLayout::setVerticalSpacing(40);` .. and between columns `QFormLayout::setHorizontalSpacing(40);`

and, IMHO, no point *manipulate* sizes of widgets or spacing of rows everytime window gets a resize .. if your window has a handful of widgets .. it will look as you expect.

sample:

```
  QFormLayout * const formlayout = new QFormLayout(this->ui->centralWidget);
  QHBoxLayout *hb1 = new QHBoxLayout;
  QHBoxLayout *hb2 = new QHBoxLayout;
  QHBoxLayout *hb3 = new QHBoxLayout;
  QLabel *hb1_layout = new QLabel("Short Text1");
  hb1_layout->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(212, 192, 255)");
  hb1_layout->setFixedSize(100,100);
  hb1->addWidget(hb1_layout);
  formlayout->addRow(hb1);
  //
  QLabel *hb2_layout = new QLabel("Long Long Long Text");
  hb2_layout->setFixedSize(200,200);
  hb2_layout->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(25, 255, 192)");
  hb2->addWidget(hb2_layout);
  formlayout->addRow(hb2);
  //
  QLabel *hb3_layout = new QLabel("Long Long Long Text too \n Long Long Long Text too \n Long Long Long Text too");
  hb3_layout->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(100, 25, 25)");
  hb3_layout->setFixedSize(300,300);
  hb3->addWidget(hb3_layout);
  formlayout->addRow(hb3);
  //
  formlayout->setHorizontalSpacing(40); // between columns
  formlayout->setVerticalSpacing(10); // between rows
  adjustSize(); // Window to contents
```